# Installing or uninstalling Kerio VPN Client - error 2738

Tags: installation, vpn, kerio

I had problems with beta version of Kerio VPN Client (KVC) and I decided to uninstall it and install older stable version. When I tried to uninstall it, I get a message: "Error 2738. Could not access VBScript run time for custom action." When I tried to install stable version of KVC without uninstalling older one, I get the same message.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Command Prompt as Administrator, and type these two commands:

```
reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11CF-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}" /f

c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 vbscript.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on my machine:

**Can't find script engine "VBScript"**

It was a VAIO laptop with stock setup, however I've removed a lot of crappy pre-installed application like McAfee. It appears that the McAfee uninstaller was not able to restore the registry and there was the following entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\McAfee\\VirusScan\\scriptsn.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
```

Trying to delete the key as suggested by Simplius didn't work because of the permissions restrictions. I had to run regedit, find this key there, right click, Permissions, change owner to Administrator, change permissions to allow Administrator full access to the key.

Then I was able to replace this value with the correct one:

```
c:\Windows\System32\vbscript.dll
```

And finally the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's an old question, but I had the same problem and the solution worked for me with a little change:

1. Open the prompt as administrator
2. For 32-bit type:

   ```
   reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11CF-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}" /f
   ```

   For 64-bit type:

   ```
   reg delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{B54F3741-5B07-11CF-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}" /f
   ```
3. For both 32-bit and 64-bit type:

   ```
   c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 vbscript.dll
   ```

The regedit folder for 64-bit Windows is different, so the previous answer wouldn't have worked.